# How do I create a new ESXI install and keep the old VMs

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm working to make a new ESXi install because the old install is on a flash drive that is still working but may fail because someone thought it was unimportant and left it in their pocket and washed it.  Anyways, it is still working but at risk of failing.  I already tried to use a USB cloning tool and it won't successfully boot off of that so that isn't working.  I think the best option is to create a new ESXi install on the new USB and then somehow import the datastore and the VMs but I don't know how well that will work.  If I were to create a new install on this new USB could I just open the datastore which is on a RAID array and start up the old VMs without a problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I'm using ESXi 6 and VMFS datastores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide version and storage info so I'm making some assumptions - like, you are using VMFS volumes and not NFS.

During the install process, it should detect your storage and see that there is an existing VMFS volume and give you the option to preserve it or overwrite it. You can preserve the existing VMFS volume and re-register the virtual machines .vmx file to add the guests back to the new host.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) I'm using ESXi 6 and the datastore is VMFS.  I'm not on site so if I were to make a new install here and then plug it in can it find the datastore and then populate the VM list automatically or will I have to manually import the VMs?